# Auto generate index.d.ts, type definitions, from a typescript module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, type-definition

If I have a TypeScript module saved as my-function.ts as follows :

```
export function myFunction (param: number): number { return param }
```

This will be compiled to JavaScript in whichever way and loose its type definitions. I am then able to create a index.d.ts file which declare this module's definitions, but this seems a bit tedious to redefine/redeclare the definitions.

Are there ways to generate the type definitions automatically from the my-function.ts file to a index.d.ts file?

Answer (score 17):

If you compile with the `--declaration` flag, TypeScript will automatically generate `.d.ts` files for you.

This mode will require that you certain types are visible so that they can be described in your `.d.ts` files.

Comment: Is there an easy way to combine them? If that's matters, I'm talking about UMD modules.

Comment: You might be talking about declaration bundling (i.e. collapsing your declarations down to one top-level `index.d.ts` file), but TypeScript currently doesn't support that.

Comment: How do people get this in definitely typed?

Answer (score 14):

### **Here's how I managed to solve it:**

### Creating the infra

1. Create an new Node package with typescript for the infra.
2. Inside the new package, make sure to configure a **tsconfig.json** with **declaration:true** Doing so will cause typescript to generate definition files which can be consumed by the users of this infra.

**My tsconfig.json:**

```json
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "declaration": true,
       "outDir": "./tsOutputs"
     },
    "include": [
      "lib/**/*.ts",
      "index.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "test/**/*.ts"
    ]
  }
```

3. Create a an **"index.ts"** file which will export the public API of the infra.

**Note:** In order to be able to cast & create instances of objects, you need to have **two different** exports per each entity. Once as **type** and another as **const**.

**Here's my index.ts:**

```
import {HttpClient as HC} from "./lib/http/http-client";

import {HttpRequest as HReq, HttpResponse as HRes} from "./lib/http/contracts";

export namespace MyJsInfra {

    export type HttpClient = HC;

    export namespace Entities {
        export type HttpRequest = HReq;
        export const HttpRequest = HReq;

        export type HttpResponse = HRes;
        export const HttpResponse = HRes;
    }
}
```

You can read more info on the reasoning behind this dual declaration in here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10058#issuecomment-236458961

4. After all of the following, when we'll run build we should have the corresponding "*.d.ts" files per each type. Now we have to handle the *package.json* of the infra, in order to pack all the items.
5. Inside the *package.json* make sure to set the *types*, *main* to point to the generated *index.d.ts* & *index.js* files.
   In addition, you have to make sure that the "*.d.ts" files are being packaged as part of infra. In my case, I've specified the following pattern in the *files* property: "tsOutputs/**/*.d.ts"

**Here's my package.json:**

```json
    {
      "name": "my-js-infra",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Infrastructure code.",
      "scripts": {
        "build":"./node_modules/.bin/tsc -p .",
        "prepublish":"npm run build",
      },
      
     "homepage": "https://github.com/Nadav/My.JS.Infra#readme",
      "devDependencies": {
       ...
        "typescript": "^2.4.2",
       ...
      },
      "dependencies": {
         ...
        "needle": "^1.4.2",
         ...
      },
      "files": [
        "tsOutputs/**/*.js",
        "tsOutputs/**/*.d.ts",
        "tsOutputs/index.d.ts"
      ],
      "types":"tsOutputs/index.d.ts",
      "main":"tsOutputs/index.js"
    }
```

**All done. Now you can publish your common code.**

---

### Consuming the code

1. Install the infra. In our case the user have to use: `npm install my-js-infra --save`
2. Modify the **tsconfig.json** of the consuming application to load the modules using the **Node** module resolution. You do so by setting **moduleResolution:true** inside the file.

**Here's my tsconfig.json:**

```json
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "es5",
            "lib": ["es5", "es6"],
            "module": "umd",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "watch": false,
            "outDir": "./tsOutputs",
            "moduleResolution":"node" /* This must be specified in order for typescript to find the my-js-infra. Another option is to use "paths" and "baseUrl". Something like:
                                            ...
                                            "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is used.
                                            "paths":{
                                                "my-js-infra":["node_modules/my-js-infra/tsOutputs/index.d.ts"]
                                            }
                                            ...
                                        */
        }
    }
```

You can read more on **module resolution in Typescript** in here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

4. Start using the code. For example:

```js
import {MyJsInfra } from "my-js-infra";

public doMagic(cmd, callback) {
    try {
        var request: MyJsInfra.Entities.HttpRequest = {
            verb: "GET",
            url: "http://www.google.com",
        };

        var client = new MyJsInfra.HttpClient();
        client.doRequest(request, (err, data) => {
            if (err)
                return callback(err, null)
            return callback(null, data);
        })
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: My `index.ts` has `module.exports = {...}`. Every other `.ts` file in module gets corresponding `.d.ts` file created properly expect `index.d.ts`, which just says `export {};`. Any suggestions?!

Comment: What is "infra"?

Comment: @JoeTidee "infrastructure", I assume